# SWRevealViewController opening method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am currently using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) to have a left menu.

I would like to know when the user is showing/closing it by dragging but I can't find any method to perform that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these two methods in [`SWRevealViewControllerDelegate`](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/blob/master/SWRevealViewController/SWRevealViewController.h#L335):

```
// The following delegate methods will be called before and after the front view moves to a position
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position;
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position;
```

These should provide sufficient information to determine when the user started opening or closing the menu, and when the interaction ended.